# How to make responsive form layout

Tags: forms, layout, flexbox, responsive

i want to do section layout consisting of inputs (as in picture). Is flexbox a good idea of doing form layout ? Well i can´t handle that even when trying to flex it. Could anyone show me how to do that perhaps in codpen,jsfiddle or smth. ? I was thinking and trying for 5 hours today. Will someone please help me ?
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking help with ("how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: The desired layout (behavior) is show in the picture. Problem is how to set it so that 3 inputs are in one row, and submit in second row under them, so that it has spaces between them and icould possibly be responsive (just like in the picture). I cannot insert code since i don´t know how to do it.